# Out of memory error when generating a large report with <cfdocumenttype="pdf">

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Here is the error: Failure in browser during Loading phase : Insufficient memory occurred during the rendering process of this document.

```
409 : <cfif showBuildings>                  
410 :   <cfdocumentsection margintop="1.9"> 
411 :   
412 :       <cfdocumentitem type="header">
```

The HTML version of the report is about 7 megs and around 500 pages printed.  After googling the issue it appears `<cfdocumenttype="pdf">`  doesn't support 'large' documents but I was unable to find the upper limit.

Can anyone suggest a workaround? Is it possible to build up the reports iteratively then stitch them back together?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your JVM memory args set at? Have you tried increasing your heap size there?

Comment: was set to 512 I just bumped it up to 1024 and I'm trying it again. The thing is the client won't want to bump this up because the server is already perilously low on memory. 
java.args=-server -Xmx512m

Comment: Bumping up the JVM memory args did in fact work. Unfortunately this isn't a workable solution for the production server : /

Comment: Even if you could build up the reports iteratively then stitch them back together, you would still have the same problem.  The end product would be too large.  You might need a bigger server.

Comment: *you would still have the same problem* Not necessarily. If the merge process does a decent job buffering, rather than maintaining the whole thing in memory, you *may* get better results. But agreed that creating pdfs generally requires a fair amount of resources. So ultimately you may still need more memory/better box anyway.

Comment: How are you serving the document, via browser or saving to server then providing download link? I typcially get better response times by saving to server file system first

Comment: Yes it's via web browser. Luckily We were able to bump up the Ram on the Prod instance so this is no longer a problem for me anymore. I'll leave it open just in case someone else finds a better workaround.

Comment: Does anyone know why PDF generation takes so much memory?  We ran into this same issue and wasn't until we allocated 4GB to ColdFusion that it could successfully create a PDF.  The PDFs final size, 5MB.  Seems absurd.  This was saving to the server, not serving.